# frequency count of dates if other column contains specific values

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, frequency, zoo

The project Im working with needs me to count frequencies by date (quarterly) if there are specific values in other column.
The data looks like this:

```
ID  Date     Grade
1   2016-Q2  A
2   2016-Q2  A
3   2016-Q3  B
4   2016-Q3  D
5   2016-Q4  D
6   2017-Q1  B
7   2017-Q1  A
8   2017-Q1  B
9   2017-Q1  C
```

I am trying to count the frequencies **of both A and B** occurring every quarter. If A or B did not occur in the quarter, it returns 0.
The output I am willing to see is:

```
Date     frequency
2016-Q2  2
2016-Q3  1
2016-Q4  0
2017-Q1  3
```

I know the code part `Result<-My_Data%>%group_by(Date)%>%summarise(frequency=n())`
but I am having real trouble finding something similar but for select values.

Help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Sample Data:

```
df <- tribble(
  ~Date,     ~Grade,
   "2016-Q2",  "A",
   "2016-Q2",  "A",
   "2016-Q3",  "B",
   "2016-Q3",  "D",
   "2016-Q4",  "D",
   "2017-Q1",  "B",
   "2017-Q1",  "A",
   "2017-Q1",  "B",
   "2017-Q1",  "C"
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not simply this?

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Date) %>%
  summarise(freq = sum(Grade %in% c("A", "B")))

# A tibble: 4 x 2
  Date     freq
  <chr>   <int>
1 2016-Q2     2
2 2016-Q3     1
3 2016-Q4     0
4 2017-Q1     3
```

or in BaseR

```
aggregate(Grade ~ Date, data = df,  FUN = function(x) sum(x %in% c("A", "B")))

     Date Grade
1 2016-Q2     2
2 2016-Q3     1
3 2016-Q4     0
4 2017-Q1     3
```

Comment: Glad that it helped.  Please accept the answer as per usual practice on SO.  You can accept only one answer however, you can upvote as many answers as you feel helped per question.

Comment: @AnilGoyal I have no idea why I over-complicated this one! Maybe yesterday was not my day!

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
Result<-My_Data%>%group_by(Grade, Date)%>%summarise(frequency=n())
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is also an easier way of achieving this. However, this works anyway:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(map_dfc(list(sum_A = "A", 
                      sum_B = "B"), ~ sum(cur_data() == .x))) %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  summarise(across(starts_with("sum"), sum), 
            count_A_B = sum(c_across(sum_A:sum_B))) %>%
  select(-c(sum_A, sum_B))

# A tibble: 4 x 2
  Date    count_A_B
  <chr>       <int>
1 2016-Q2         2
2 2016-Q3         1
3 2016-Q4         0
4 2017-Q1         3
```